# Fetch data from mongo, useState is undefined

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am fetching data from mongo, I am getting data, but useState is still undefined.

```
const [x, setX] = useState([])

const fetchData = async () => {
  
    try {
      
       await axios.get('/api/mongo')
       .then( res => {
        const data = res.data

        setX(data)
        
       }).catch((err) => {
          setErr(err)
       }).finally(() => {
          
       })
     
    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error)
    }
  }

 useEffect(() => {
  fetchData()
 },[])

console.log(x)
```

console.log show me this message

```
[]
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
```

How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: UseEffect only fires AFTER the first render. So initially your useState value will be the default one and only after the component is rendered the first time it will fetch the data. its  a normal behavior

Comment: How can I fix it?  If I set setX() or setX(null), still  have problem. THANK YOU

Comment: I am using useEffect() to avoid infinitive loop, correct ?

Comment: you are using the useEffect correctly. In order to have the data on the first render you have few options. 1. do a server-side rendering - this way initial data will be already pre-rendered. 2. do the fetching BEFORE going into this component so the initial value would already exist. The data can be stored on redux or just react-provided context. But besides these 2 - not much can be done. If you doing a client-sided app - the data will be first null on the first render regardless. The solution for you would be to implement a loader - the first render show a spinner, after fetch show data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With simply react - you can not achieve what you like.

React flow is strict and basic. When the component renders - the `useState` value will be the initial value you provide. It will render the entire page HTML and once the initial render is done only then `useEffect` will fire. ALL `useEffect` fire in the initial render regardless of the dependency array. During the second render it also applies the refs.

So in your case - initial render happens with your state value being `undefined`. After first render it will fire the `useEffect` and fetch data and set it as a state that will force it to re-render again and only then show the data.

To combat this you could use like nextjs for server side rendering so the client gets the page with initial data already pre-loaded. But to do this with simply react, besides fetching this data before entering this component, is to add a loader.

A loader is a spinner to shows loading animation to indicate a user that something is happening. To add this is simple:

1. Add a new state for loading indication that has initial data as `true` `const [isLoading, setIsLoading] =  useState(true)`.
2. Add a state for error handling `const [error, setError] = useState()`

In the fetch function add in `.finally` set the loader state to false `setIsLoading(false)` indicating that the data has been fetched or at least tried. In the `catch` add errors in the state `setError(error)`.

In the html section do a check

```
return <div>
    {isLoading 
        ? <Spinner /> 
        : !!error 
            ? <div>An error has accored</div> 
            : <div>Data has been fetched successfully and can be used {x}</div> } 
    </div>
```

Of course, you should also add a check if value `x` exists and if don't - display 'no data was fetched; message.